# How to code the partial extensions that Linq to SQL autogenerates?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, partial-methods

I made a class from Linq to SQL Clasees with VS 2008 SP1 Framework 3.5 SP1, in this case I extended the partial

```
partial void UpdateMyTable(MyTable instance){
   // Business logic
   // Validation rules, etc.
}
```

My problem is when I execute db.SubmitChanges(), it executes UpdateMyTable and makes the validations but it doesn't update, I get this error:

```
[Exception: Deliver]
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SendOnValidate(MetaType type, TrackedObject item, ChangeAction changeAction) +197
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ValidateAll(IEnumerable`1 list) +255
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +76
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +331
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() +19
```

Comment: Actually there is a policy on non-English questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- if you provide this method, you must perform the update in the method.

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882671.aspx

- If you implement the Insert, Update and Delete methods in your partial class, the LINQ to SQL runtime will call them **instead** of its own default methods when SubmitChanges is called.

Try **MiTabla.OnValidate**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement this method but not do the update yourself you make the method call ExecuteDynamicUpdate(item);

Likewise ExecuteDynamicDelete and ExecuteDynamicInsert for DeleteMyTable and InsertMyTable respectively.